# Could someone explain the function of while loop in javascript getCookie() to me?

Tags: javascript, cookies, while-loop

sorry for a question to ask...
Below is the tutorial of getCookie code from W3C School

Would someone teach me what is the function of `while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);` , and since it is while loop, why won't it keep repeating and stuck there?

Thanks...

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
    }

   }
```

Comment: while the first character is an empty space, remove the first character. It's trying to trim empty space of the front of a string

Comment: "W3C School" — W3Schools is a purveyor of low quality tutorials. The W3C is a standards organisation. They are not the same organisation and you should avoid confusing them.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the function of while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);

It removes spaces at the front of `c`.

> since it is while loop, why won't it keep repeating and stuck there?

`while` loops only repeat *while* the value is true. You can't have a string made up of **infinite** spaces.

Comment: @ssube — It will remove multiple spaces. It is a poor version of trim (which removes multiple spaces).

Comment: please can any one tell me if there any problem to replace the function in the question with this , function getCokkie(cookie) {
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let cookieslist = decodedCookie.split(cookie+"=");
  if (cookieslist.length > 1)  {
  return cookieslist[1].split(";")[0].trim();
  } else {
  return "";
  }

}