# Javascript cookie and statements

Tags: javascript

Hello Guys Now I currently learn javascript in W3school platform almost completed but I have one doubt that is in JS cookies

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Why do we use

```
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
}
```

this `while` statement and `charAt` in this part.  Please explain thank you

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about it? Are you aware of what `c.charAt(0) == ' '` does? Or what `c = c.substring(1)` does? Or how a while-loop works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could someone explain the function of while loop in javascript getCookie() to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137266/could-someone-explain-the-function-of-while-loop-in-javascript-getcookie-to-me)

Comment: It's a very convoluted way of writing `var c = ca[i].trimLeft();`.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies usually get set with the following pattern:

entry; entry; entry; entry ...and so on.

Using `split(";")` you will get an array that looks like this:

[ entry]
[ entry]
[ entry]
[ entry]

```
c.charAt(0) == ' ';
```

just removes the leading blank(s).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0):

This loop removes the white spaces prefixed in a string. The while loop will continue "while" the condition is true. So, it will continue as long as the first character of the string is a white space. Inside the loop, it creates a new string by removing the current first character and assign it to the same variable `c`. So, you can think of this as just removing the first character.

There is the `String.trim()` method - but removes both leading and trailing white spaces.

```js
let c = '        foo';
    console.log(c)
    
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
  c = c.substring(1);
}

console.log(c)
```